# What is the reason of parse error in go-swagger redoc URL?

Tags: go-swagger, redoc

I was working on documentation for APIs. I've used [Go-Swagger](https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger) for the same. It's working for regular **Docs** but not for **Redoc**.

Here are my implementation details:

```
router.StaticFile("/swagger", "./api/swagger.yaml")

opts := middleware.SwaggerUIOpts{SpecURL: "/swagger", Path: "/docs"}
sh := middleware.SwaggerUI(opts, nil)
router.GET("/docs", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
    sh.ServeHTTP(ctx.Writer, ctx.Request)
})

opts1 := middleware.RedocOpts{SpecURL: "/swagger", Path: "/redoc"}
sh1 := middleware.Redoc(opts1, nil)
router.GET("/redoc", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
    sh1.ServeHTTP(ctx.Writer, ctx.Request)
})
```

As you can see, the docs are working correctly:
[image]

But I'm facing issues with redoc:
[image]

I also tried to load different library for Redoc: "https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js" but it too did not work.

I'm using this command to generate the swagger.yaml file:

```
swagger generate spec -o ./api/swagger.json --scan-models
```

Please let me know what's the actual issue. I'm not able to find anything.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the above issue, not an exact solution, but a change in code.

Instead of using the above code for integrating redoc middleware, I used this:

```
opts1 := middleware.RedocOpts{SpecURL: "/swagger", Path: "/redoc", RedocURL: "https://rebilly.github.io/ReDoc/releases/latest/redoc.min.js"}
sh1 := middleware.Redoc(opts1, nil)
router.GET("/redoc", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
    sh1.ServeHTTP(ctx.Writer, ctx.Request)
})
```

So, we are actually providing and overwriting the `RedocURL` to be used.